# Is there a way to stop website I search through Chrome Android requesting me SMS reading?

Tags: sms, chrome-for-android

While I'm logging in website through SMS it always asks me to read SMS and code inside of it.
Is there a way to prevent such requests?

Comment: Does it ask to read incoming message(s) e.g. to get some SMS phone number verification code or all SMS messages?

Comment: It asks to read only incoming messages.

Comment: Then even if you would click yes, Chrome could only read specially formatted SMS messages (contain special data that bind it to chrome). This restriction applies on Android 9+. Thus it only makes sense for one-time SMS verification or special TAN codes.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood what you meant. I don't want Chrome read SMS nor push up access notifications. I have Android 9. Is there no way to even restrict Chrome suggesting me such choices, to make such settings 'always deny'?

Comment: I understand what you are asking. What I wrote is just a note that even if you would accidentally press yes when Chrome asks the effect would be very limited. I am wondering what sites are trying to get SMS reception permission. As I explained receiving SMS only makes sens in very special cases and thus the sites using this feature should be very limited, too. In addition the site has to have your mobile number which is another limitation.

Comment: It's government site which uses SMS code as 2FA while I'm login in.